# Show or Hiding charts in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

i'm very new to Tableau.

i have a bar chart and another column chart which have relative information to thebar chart.

what i would like to achieve is when user clicks bar of the chart, another chart will show with the corresponding data.

I achieved this, but I need to show the chart when the use clicks the bar's only.It should hide by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter actions and set your target sheet to "Exclude all values" in the "Clearing the Selection will:" section. For more information, check our the docs. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions.htm